# Fit two binary images (panorama?)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have several binary images which represent a partial map of an area (~4m radius) and were taken ~0.2m apart, for example:

[image: First map picture] 
[image: Second map picture]

(Sorry for the different axis limit).

If you look closely, you'll see that the first image is about 20cm to the right.

I want to be able to create a map of the area from several pictures like this.
I've tried several methods, such as Matlab's register but couldn't find any good algorithm for this purpose. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say: register. There are a lot of image registration methods! also you know that you want to register the scale/translation/rotation, but all is rigid motion, so it shoudl be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible routes:

Use [imregister](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregister.html). This does registration based on image intensity. You will probably want a rigid transform.

However, this will require your data to be an image (matrix), which it doesn't look like it currently is.

Alternatively, you can use control points. These are common (labelled) points in each image which provide a reference to determine the transform.

Matlab has a built in function to determine control points, [cpselect](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cpselect.html). However, again this requires image data. You may be better of writing your own function to do this or just selecting control points manually.

Once you have control points you can determine the transform between them using [fitgeotrans](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html)